# How to limit space which windows 10 file history may use

Tags: windows-10, file-history

In windows 8.1 file history it was possible to limit file history to use only 5% (or 10%, 20% etc) of available disk space.

In windows 10 this setting seems to have disappeared.

- How much space will windows 10 file history consume? (e.g. with "until space is needed" for the "keep saved versions" setting)
- How can that amount of space be limited?

Answer (score 4):

**Q:** How much space will windows 10 file history consume? (e.g. with "until space is needed" for the "keep saved versions" setting)

**A:** it will use all of it.

---

**Q:** How can that amount of space be limited?

**A:** Create a separate partition on the drive you wish to use for File History, and use this. This will allow you to specify exactly how much it uses.